# FIFO Implementation using SQL server

Tags: sql-server, fifo

I am looking for SQL server implementation of FIFO. For customers of a large company, I have 2 datasets with points earned in one dataset and points redeemed and expired in each year in another dataset.

The target is to determine the points redeemed and expired out of the points earned in any given year. So, obviously, the redeemed and expired points will have to be assigned to the earned points on a first in first out basis.

The datasets look as follows:

Points earned:

```
ID   year   earn
1    2000   100
1    2001   150
1    2002   75
1    2003   10
1    2004   120
```

Points burned:

```
ID   Year   Type   points
1    2001   burn    50
1    2001   exp     20
1    2003   burn    120
1    2004   exp     100
1    2006   exp     20
```

Combining the two datasets, we should get a dataset like this:

Combined dataset:

```
ID   Year   Earn   Burn   exp
1    2000   100    80     20
1    2001   150    90     60
1    2002   75     0      60
1    2003   10     0      0
1    2004   120    0      0
```

Simply, the burned and expired points are being assigned to points earned on a first in first out basis. The dataset is huge and cannot be exported in excel. Code to do the above on SQL server will be of huge help

Comment: If points burned and expired in the tables you already have were independently validated (i.e. you cannot burn more points than you have, etc.), and expiry is done on a yearly basis, then you can simply sum all the points earned, and subtract those burned and expired. That will give you the points you currently have and for which you can issue a burn request. You can add a WHERE year < X to know how many points were available before year X, and are then eligible for expiration. This allows you to create a new yearly entry in the burn/expiry table for the current year.

Comment: Your logic here isn't making sense to me.  Namely, your combined data set doesn't match your points burned table at all.  You're going to have to explain the math to me on that.  Beyond that, this just looks like double-entry bookkeeping.  One table of credits and another table of debits.

Comment: Here is how the points are being assigned:
- There are 100 points earned in 2000 to start with. So, whatever points are redeemed/expired will have to be deducted from these 100 points first
- The first time points are either redeemed/expired is in 2001 when 50 points were redeemed and 20 points got expired. So, these would be deducted from the points earned in 2000. So, after assigning these 50 redeemed points and 20 expired points to 2000, there are still 30 points left to be used in 2000

Comment: Continued from above:
- The next usage is 120 points in 2003. So, 30 of them will be deducted from the balance in 2000 and the remaining will be deducted from the points earned in later years
- If we continue to assign points in this manner, the above table is what we would obtain

Comment: @Iserni - It's not as easy as you say it is. You probably haven't understood the problem. I came out with an algorithm when there are no expiration points but having expiration points is an extra complication. What you proposed is exactly what I thought when I saw this problem. But if you actually start working on it, you would understand that it isn't that easy

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I certainly do not have the most efficient code, but i have thew following algorithm to assign points redeemed an expired using FIFO logic

1. Calculate the maximum points that will be used by an individual. This would include both the points redeemed and expired. Target is to assign these points to different earnings transactions
2. Figure out the earnings transaction that cross the maximum points used. Anything transaction below this should not have any points assigned under redeemed or expired. So, make redeemed and expired 0 for all these transactions. Now, we only need to assign points to the other transactions left
3. For each earnings transaction, figure out the transaction from the used table that crosses the points earned in that transaction. Now for this earnings transaction, the total expiration points that need to be assigned is the total number of points expired until the corresponding transaction in the used table + whatever is left from this transaction from the used table depending on whether it's a redeemed transaction or expired transaction. Similarly, points redeemed also need to assigned

The algorithm worked perfectly. I could have done a better job with coding. It took me 3 hours to run on a dataset with 150 million records